# AEM Page properties

Tags: aem

I have added a dropdown under a tab in page properties and that dropdown has two options and corresponding to those two options , we have textfields. Now suppose I choose 1st option ,corresponding to 1st option , textfield appears and I fill that and save the page properties. Now what happening is when I again open the page properties,the dropdown value (which was chosen) is there as it is as 1st option but the textfield corresponding to it doesn't appear unless I click on the 1st option (or corresponding option) again.

I am using the same dropdown in a component but there is works well and but not at page property.

Comment: you can write additional event during load of dialog, and call that function which you are calling at time of change event of dropdown

Comment: Can you post some code to check the login behind the info?